# Custom Bootstrap Indicator with arrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create this red indicator design I made in Photoshop using Bootstrap.

[image]

With all the code

[Here is the link to my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tx2jamp/2/)

No matter what I try I can't get the triangle to line up, nor can I get the transparent toolbar area to stretch across the div. Additional, and I have tried changing the `z-index` the arrow appears under the white sub-nav bar, and the white border doesn't seem to wrap around the triangle.

***Any help from a guru?***

But my design looks more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something similar

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/4tx2jamp/3/

**Snippet Below**

```css
/* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */

  .navbar {
   margin-bottom    : 0;
   border-radius    : 0;
   background-color : #2a5e8d;
   border-width     : 0;
   }

  /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
  .row.content {
   height           : 450px;
   background-color : #e2e2e2;
   }

  .content-nav {
   background-color : #fff;
   height           : 25px;
   }

  /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
  .sidenav {
   padding-top      : 30px;
   background-color : #373737;
   height           : 100%;
   }

  .indicator {
   margin-top      : 0;
   margin-bottom   : 0;
   margin-left     : -20px;
   margin-right    : -16px;
   padding         : 0;
   list-style      : none;
   background      : #e74f50;
   color           : #fff;
   text-decoration : none;
   text-align      : right;
   font-size       : 10px;
   border-top      : 2px solid #fff;
   border-bottom   : 2px solid #fff;
     position:relative;
   }

  .indicator:after {
   content      : "";
   float        : right;
   position     : absolute;
   top          : 0;
   right        : -21px;
   width        : 0;
   height       : 0;
   border-color : transparent transparent transparent #e74f50;
   border-style : solid;
            z-index:5;

   border-width : 44px 0 44px 21px;
   }

  .indicator:before {
   content      : "";
   float        : right;
   position     : absolute;
   top          : -3px;
   right        : -23px;
   width        : 0;
   height       : 0;
   border-color : transparent transparent transparent white;
   border-style : solid;
            border-width: 47px 0px 47px 23px;
            height: calc(100% + 2px);
            z-index:4;
   }

  .indicator .title {
   float       : left;
   padding-top : 18px;
   /*line-height : 42px;*/
   position    : relative;
   font-size   : 24px;
   width       : 100%;

   }

  .indicator span.tools {
   background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   width      : 100%;
   font-size  : 18px;
   display: inline-block;
   }

  .indicator span.tools:after {
       content: '';
                border-color: transparent transparent transparent  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
                border-width: 0px 0px 26px 12px;
                border-style: solid;
                position: absolute;
                right: -12px;
                z-index: 6;
   }

  .indicator .tools span.glyphicon {
   color        : #e2e2e2;
   padding-left : 10px;
   size         : 8px;
   }

  .text-dropshadow {
   -webkit-text-shadow : 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
   -moz-text-shadow    : 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
   text-shadow         : 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
   }

  .dropshadow {
   -webkit-box-shadow : 0px 6px 6px -2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow    : 0px 6px 6px -2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
   box-shadow         : 0px 6px 6px -2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
   }

  .rightshadow {

   -webkit-box-shadow : 7px 0px 6px -2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
   -moz-box-shadow    : 7px 0px 6px -2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
   box-shadow         : 7px 0px 6px -2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
   }

  /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
  footer {
   background-color : #555;
   color            : white;
   padding          : 15px;
   }

  /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
  @media screen and (max-width : 767px) {
   .sidenav {
    height  : auto;
    padding : 15px;
    }

   .row.content {
    height : auto;
    }
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
 <div class="container-fluid  ">

 </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
 <div class="row content">
  <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav rightshadow">
   <div class="indicator rightshadow">
    <p class="title text-dropshadow">Some text </p>
    <span class="tools text-dropshadow ">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
    </span>

   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9 text-left">
   <div class="row content-nav dropshadow">&nbsp;</div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is great! Thank you for the help!